# Does this 'Sing like no people listening to you' make sense?

Tags: grammar

> Sing like no people listening to you.

This sentence means that sing like that no people are listening to you.

Is the sentence 'Sing like no people listening to you' right expression?
**I mean that can "be verb" be omitted in this sentence.**

Comment: The verb- to-be cannot be dropped there.

Answer (score 6):

'No people' sounds strange in this sentence. It is more common to say 'no one'.

'listening' is incorrect. It should be 'no people **are** listening' or 'no one **is** listening'.

'Sing like no one is listening to you' is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer **nobody** instead of *no people* and don't forget a 'verb to be' before a progressive verb

> Nobody is listening

Or in this context

> No people are listening